# Counting fields filled out

Tags: asp-classic

Quick summary of my question: I want to display the number of fields a user filled out.

I am new to learning ASP and I have looked and have not found a solution. I generated a sample page that is simple compared to what I need help with, but same idea.

When the user goes to the first page, he is obviously given three text boxes.
When he submits the form, he is shown information he submitted with the number of fields filled out. I am trying loop through each field and if the number is greater than 0, to add one to a counter named tt.

Pass 2 shows me the loop, rather than giving me the value of tt. I tried putting the loop using response.write but that didn't work.

```
<html>
<body>

<%
sub pass1
%>
Pass 1 <P>
<form action="count_p.asp"  method = "post">
<input type="text" name="t1"><BR>
<input type="text" name="t2" ><BR>
<input type="text" name="t3"><BR>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="2">
<input type="submit" value="submit query">




<%
end sub

sub pass2
  response.write "<P>Pass 2 tokenvalue="+cstr(tokenvalue)

t1=request.form("t1")
t2=request.form("t2")
t3=request.form("t3")



response.write "<P>t4=" +  t1
response.write "<P>t4="  +t2
response.write "<P>t4="  +t3
%>

tt=0
for i=1 to 3
    if t + cstr(i)  > 0 then
    tt=tt+1
    end if
then


response.write "<P>Fields filled = " + tt



<%
end sub



tokenvalue=request.form("token")
select case tokenvalue
case ""
   call pass1
case "2"
  call pass2
case "3"
  call pass3

end select
%>


</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Is your question on classic ASP or ASP.net? The code looks like ASP.

Comment: Looks like it could be MVC2 using VB?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dynamic variable names. They aren't supported. Try this:

```vbs
'Here we are splitting all the form values
'into an array. Your values will come in
'looking something like this:
'
' t1=4&t2=323&t3=3
'
'after we split them, you'll have 3 sets
'of values that look like:
'
' aFormNamesAndValues(0) = "t1=4"
' aFormNamesAndValues(1) = "t2=323"
' aFormNamesAndValues(2) = "t3=3"

aFormNamesAndValues = Split(Request.Form,"&")

tt=0
for i=0 to 2
    'Ok, splitting once again, this time on the
    'equals character. Now we will have an array
    'with 2 values, the name of the form field
    'and the value it holds, we can check each
    'value and perform some logic on it:
    aNameAndAValue = Split(aFormNamesAndValues(i),"=")

    if aNameAndAValue(0) = "t" & (i+1) then
        if aNameAndAValue(1) > 0 then
            tt=tt+1
        end if
    end if
then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Eval` method for this - usually it's frowned upon, but on this case it's valid usage:

```vbs
tt=0
For i=1 to 3
    curValue = Eval("t" & i)
    If IsNumeric(curValue) Then
        If CLng(curValue)>0 Then
            tt = tt + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

As you can also see, you need to convert the value to number using CLng to have proper comparison.